# Specify custom DNS Server when downloading using System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to filter submitted web sites by attempting to browse them while bouncing the request off of OpenDNS.  If the page received is the OpenDNS page, I'll assume the page shoudld be blocked.

How might I accomplish this task using the System.Net.WebClient class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebClient` class relies on the `Dns` class which calls into the system and uses the currently configured DNS settings. If you go down this route the only way to do what you want is to change the DNS settings first which is probably not an option for you.

Instead, either take a look at a thrid-party control like [DnDns](http://dndns.codeplex.com/) (free, open source) or just call `nslookup` and parse the results as [detailed here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/63566-simple-dns-lookup-application/).

Comment: Thanks Chris.  DnDns is cool and works well for querying OpenDNS, however it doesn't actually solve the problem.  Specifically, I need to know if OpenDNS would block the requested URI.  Just querying the service still returns valid IP info, even if the site would otherwise be blocked.

Comment: As and update, I decided to use DnDns.  The caveat is that whatever server I run it from has to have its static IP registered with OpenDNS.  When I query OpenDNS from behind a registered IP, it will return the same IP for any blocked site.  Thanks Chris.

Comment: Glad to hear @Matt P. I started looking into an API (which doesn't exist as far as I could tell) and was hoping something like this would happen.